# How to make continuous random NaNs in python array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Assume that there's an array with a random number

```
[[ 1. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 5. 7.]
[ 1. 3. 6. 4. 4. 0. 4. 0.]
[ 5. 0. 5. 1. 3. 0. 5. 1.]
[ 2. 1. 5. 4. 6. 1. 3. 4.]
[ 2. 1. 0. 0. 6. 1. 2. 1.]
[ 3. 5. 7. 2. 9. 6. 3. 5.]]
```

I want to introduce **4 continuous `NaN`** in this array as below. 
Also, `NaN` must occupy about **20%** of total array, which means missing rate of 20%. This array has 48 components, so 10 components of `NaN` are required. 
A block of continuous `NaN`s should be introduced in this array.

*If possible, I want to adjust the continuity ratio and the missing rate. (The continuity ratio means the number of continuous NaN...)*

```
[[ 1. 3. NaN NaN NaN NaN 5. 7.]
[ 1. 3. 6. 4. 4. 0. 4. 0.]
[ 5. 0. 5. 1. 3. 0. 5. 1.]
[ NaN NaN NaN NaN 6. 1. 3. 4.]
[ 2. 1. 0. 0. 6. 1. 2. 1.]
[ 3. 5. 7. 2. 9. 6. NaN NaN]]
```

There are lots of code making random NaNs in the array, but I can't figure out how to replace values with continuous NaNs. 
Thanks first for your help!

Comment: I see there are only 2 continuous  `NaN` at the end. Is it on purpose? Is it fine if you have 6 continuous `NaN`? (intersection of two groups of 4 `NaN`)

Comment: @Andrea  The array should have 10 ```NaN``` so I just put last 2 ```NaN``` at the end, but it doesn't matter where it goes. It also doesn't matter if I have 6 continuous ```NaN```. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest this approach, which is far from being optimal, but it works:

```
## data
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

a = np.array([[1., 3., 4., 5., 1., 2., 5., 7.],
            [1., 3., 6., 4., 4., 0., 4., 0.],
            [5., 0., 5., 1., 3., 0., 5., 1.],
            [2., 1., 5., 4., 6., 1., 3., 4.],
            [2., 1., 0., 0., 6., 1., 2., 1.],
            [3., 5., 7., 2., 9., 6., 3., 5.]])

## NaN statistics definition
nan_ratio = 0.2
nan_seq_len = 4
number_of_nan_seq = int(nan_ratio * a.size / nan_seq_len)
nan_position = np.random.randint(0, a.size-nan_seq_len, size=number_of_nan_seq)

## NaN insertion
nan_indexes = np.ones([nan_position.size, nan_seq_len]) * nan_position[:, np.newaxis] + np.arange(0, nan_seq_len)
a_shape = a.shape
a_flat = a.flatten()
a_flat[nan_indexes.astype('int')] = np.nan
a = a_flat.reshape(a_shape)
```

output `a`:

```
array([[ 1.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  5.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  6.,  4.,  4.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  5.,  1.,  3.,  0.,  5.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  5.,  4., nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  1., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  7.,  2.,  9.,  6.,  3.,  5.]])
```